# In magento, update customer entity if customer has at least one order

Tags: magento, updates

I have created a custom attribute is_buyer for user which will be set to 1 after order post event.

Now I want to set 'is_buyer' to 1 for old users which have at least one order.

I can do this using foreach loop but I want to do this with a single query.

Any body knows how to write query for mentioned task using magento.

I have already written one time script using loop.

```
    <?php
    set_time_limit(0);
    $customers = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id')
            ->addAttributeToFilter(array(array('attribute' => 'is_buyer', 'null' => true)), '', 'left');

    $orders = Mage::getSingleton('sales/order')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('customer_id');

    foreach ($customers as $customer) {   
        $orders->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customer->getId());
        if ($orders->count() > 0) {
            $customer->setData('is_buyer', 1);        
        } else {
             $customer->setData('is_buyer', 0);     
        }
        $customer->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this slow approach to set the old users one time. And use an observer
to set the customer information ad hoc for new orders. So you only need to run the above script once. You can actually do some performance tuning...save and load in foreach is bad practice, but as you only need to run the script one it might not matter...

```
$customers = Mage::getModel('customer/customer)->getCollection();

foreach ($customers as $_customer){

        $_orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',$_customer->getId());                        
        if ($_orders->count()){
            $customer->setIsBuyer();
            $customer->save();
        }
}
```

The event is:

```
<sales_order_place_after>    
    <observers>
       <your_observer>
         <type>singleton</type>
         <class>YOUR_CLASS</class>
         <method>YOUR_METHOD</method>
       </your_observer>    
     </observers> 
 </sales_order_place_after>
```

The actual observer method (proof of concept but slow):

```
public static function YOUR_METHOD($observer) {
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $order = $event->getOrder();
    $order->getCustomerId();
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($order->getCustomerId());
    $customer->setIsBuyer();
    $customer->save();
}
```

Comment: Please see my question, just updated, I need one query to do this, looping is another option will take time when module will run first time.

Comment: So why dont you tell this...you have now edited your question. Run the script one time (execution time might not matter) and go on with the observer solution for setting the information ad hoc - to avoid running the initial script ever again...

Comment: have managed this with module version, but I need to do this with out loop. My dev manager wants to see this with out loop :) so I have assigned ticket to him :)

Answer (score 0):

So here is installer code which can do this in one query instead of loop.

```
/** @var Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup $setup */
$setup = $this;
$setup->startSetup();

$setup->addAttribute('customer', 'is_buyer', array(
    'type' => 'int',
    'input' => 'boolean',
    'label' => 'Is Buyer',
    'global' => 1,
    'visible' => 1,
    'required' => 0,
    'user_defined' => 0,
    'default' => '0',
    'visible_on_front' => 0,
    'position' => 200
));
$attributeId = $this->getAttributeId('customer', 'is_buyer');
$setup->run("
     INSERT INTO customer_entity_int (`entity_type_id`, `attribute_id`, `entity_id`, `value`)
    SELECT 1, {$attributeId}, c.entity_id, 1
    FROM customer_entity c
    WHERE c.entity_id IN (
       SELECT s.customer_id FROM sales_flat_order s
        WHERE s.customer_id IS NOT NULL
        GROUP BY s.customer_id
   )
   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `value` = VALUES(`value`);
");
```